# drupal global variables

Tags: drupal

How can I access the global variables in drupal

Answer (score 7):

Example:

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == 1) { print t('I am superuser!'); }
```

[List of globals](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals). 
Investigate structure of global via `print_r($user)` or `dsm($user)` (if devel module installed)ю

Answer (score 0):

We can access global variables using the keyword 'global' . 
global $language , global $user are some of the global variables.